# Pass object by reference when containing a vector

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class that contains (among other things) a large vector. I need to pass an object of this class to a function.

According to best practices, in C++ vectors and arrays should be passed by reference. My question is, is it correct to do so as well with objects given that they contain vectors?

See the following example where I illustrate the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class
    Test
{
  private:
  public:
    std::vector<int> test_vector;
};


void asdd(Test &t)
{
    cout << t.test_vector.size() << endl;
    cout << t.test_vector.push_back(100) << endl;

}

int main()
{
    Test asd;
    asd.test_vector.resize(1000);
    asdd(asd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a class that contains (among other things) a large vector. I need to pass an object of this class to a function.

That's pretty normal.

> According to best practices, in C++ vectors and arrays should be passed by reference.

Not sure that is what the best practice says. I bet it says "pass by const reference". But you need to pass by reference if you want to modify the original value from inside the function.

> My question is, is it correct to do so as well with objects given that they contain vectors?

That sounds perfectly reasonable. **BUT** is it it the best thing to do? That will depend on context. In your example above I would argue that it is **not**. In this simple case I would have `asdd()` a member method. That way you don't need to pass the object or the vector, you also don't need to expose a member variable as a public.

> See the following example where I illustrate the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Don't do this.
// This will cause you untold misery in the future.
// Prefer to use the prefix `std::` in-front of standard members.
//
// For more details read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065
using namespace std;

class
    Test             // Why is this on a different line?
                     // That makes it awkward to read.
{
  private:           // Not needed by default members are private.
  public:
    // Should not make member objects publicly available.
    // Any object that is part of the state should be a private member
    // whose state change should be controlled via methods to protect
    // the object from going into an invalid state.
    //
    // Your exception to this rule is property bags.
    // But property bags are usually expressed as structures.
    std::vector<int> test_vector;
};

// In C++ the `*` and the `&` are considered part of the type information
// thus they are usually placed with the type not the value.
// Note: This is the exact opposite of C programs.
//   => void asdd(Test& t)
void asdd(Test &t)
{
    // Prefer to use "\n" instead of `std::endl`
    // The difference is that `std::endl` will flush the stream.
    // This can cause some sever degredation in performance when you
    // have a lot of output.
    //
    // Note: Streams will auto flush themselves when needed.
    //       Special work has gone into making `std::cin` and `std::cout`
    //       Flush correctly for user intput.
    cout << t.test_vector.size() << endl;
    cout << t.test_vector.push_back(100) << endl;

}

int main()
{
    Test asd;
    asd.test_vector.resize(1000);
    asdd(asd);

    // In C++ main() is very special.
    // You don't need to return 0 as the compiler will plant this automatically.
    //
    // Usually you only see a return when there is a possibility of 
    // main returning a non zero value, so it gives you a clue to go
    // and look for the error conditions in main(). Since you don't
    // have any error conditions then you may as well drop this.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `In C++ the '*' and the '&' are considered part of the type information` while this makes sense it seems a lot of code even in the STL uses `foo &bar` instead of `foo& bar`. Is there an official recommendation about this somewhere?

Comment: @Yuri: Nothing "official", but the [CPPCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-ptr) covers emphasizing types over expressions/grammar.

Comment: @yuri http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace